# Powershell scripts work when run directly but not when called by another

Tags: function, powershell, nested

I have a long list of simple jobs I would like to *somewhat* automate. It's simple stuff, grab or post info via API and build some reports, nothing fancy.

I decided to build a master script which directs out to a variety of other scripts, each handling its own job. Each one of those little scripts, reference functions from a **Utility** script which I built that has functions which are common to all the other simple job scripts.

Each of the scripts work perfectly when I run them directly, however, when I try to run them via the master script, which routes to them, they all fail.

One example is that in many cases I need to fetch data from an API but get capped at 1000 object returns when I need 10k+. To solve this, I built a function which recursively calls itself until there is no more data left to collect. Again, this works when called by itself but not from the master script, for some reason, it bails out after the first run (should run 10+ times in this case). Then, it returns nothing.

I am thinking maybe this has something to do with how I am scoping the functions/variables?? Not sure. I have tried scoping to `Global, Local & Script` but none seem to work. Here's some of the code...

```
*Master Director Script runs script based on user input*

...

&$choice_hash[$action].script_path
```

```
$ScriptDirectory = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
. "$ScriptDirectory\Utilities.psm1"

$user_data          = $null
$env_choice         = $null
$csv_output_path    = $null
$collated_user_data = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

function selectEnv {
    $global:env_choice = Read-Host @"
    > Select an Environment: [Prod] or [Dev]

    Your Choice
"@
    if ($env_choice -ne 'Prod' -and $env_choice -ne 'Dev') {
        consoleCmt $env_choice
        consoleCmt 'Invalid Choice. Try again...'
        selectEnv
    } else {
        if ($env_choice -eq 'Prod') {
            $global:csv_output_path = '\\etoprod\******\Exports\Report_Users_Prod.csv'  
        } else {
            $global:csv_output_path = '\\etoprod\******\Exports\Report_Users_Dev.csv'
        }

        $global:user_data = process_data $env_choice 'api/xm/1/people?embed=roles&limit=1000'
    }
}

function processUsersData {
     foreach($user in $user_data) {
        $user_roles     = ''
        $role_divider   = ','

        for($i = 0; $i -lt $user.roles.data.length; $i++) {
            # Only append a comma if there are more, otherwise leave blank for CSV deliniation 
            if ($i -eq $user.roles.data.length - 1) {
                $role_divider = ''
            }

            $user_roles += $user.roles.data[$i].name + $role_divider
        }

        # Build ordered hash table with above data
        $sanatized_user = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{id = $user.targetName; firstName = $user.firstName; lastName = $user.lastName; siteName = $user.site.name; roles = $user_roles }

        # Shovel into storage array used for building the CSV
        $global:collated_user_data += $sanatized_user
    }
}

notice 'Initiating Groups Report Script'
selectEnv
processUsersData
exportCsv $collated_user_data $csv_output_path
```

*Utility Script (relevant functions being called)*

```
     $res      = $null
        $content  = @()

...

    function process_data($env, $url) {
            fetch_data $env $url

            foreach($i in $res.data) {
                $global:content += $i
            }

            if($res.links.next) {
                fetch_more $env $res.links.next
            }

            return $content  **Should return full collection of data, but fails after one pass**
        }

        function fetch_data($env, $url) {
            $base = generateEnvBase $env
            $path = "$base/$url"

            $req        = Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri $path -Method GET
            $global:res = ConvertFrom-Json $req
        }

        function fetch_more($env, $url) {
            $base = generateEnvBase $env
            $path = "$base$url"

            $req  = Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri $path -Method GET
            $res  = ConvertFrom-Json $req

            foreach($i in $res.data) {
                $global:content += $i
            }

            if($res.links.next) {
                fetch_more $env $res.links.next 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in advance if I have not followed procedure or etiquette, I'm new here.

This should work if you declare all variables in Main.ps1 that are needed by functions. You could also use the "Script" scope when creating a new variable inside a function that you want to use outside the function. Example `$Script:Var = "Stuff"` created inside a function will be available to whole script.

Directory Structure

```
C:\Script\Root
|   Main.ps1
\---Utilities
        fetch_data.ps1
        fetch_more.ps1
        processUsersData.ps1
        process_data.ps1
        selectEnv.ps1
```

Main.ps1

```
#---[ Initization ]---#
# Strings
[String]$RootPath = $PSScriptRoot
[String]$UtilPath = "$($RootPath)\Utilities"
[String]$env_choice = $null
[String]$csv_output_path = $null
# Arrays
[Array]$user_data = @()
[Array]$content = @()
[Array]$collated_user_data = @()
[Array]$res = @()

#---[ Source in Utilities ]---#
# Get the scripts
$Utilities = Get-ChildItem -Path "$UtilPath" -File | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".ps1"}
# Source in each one
foreach ($Item in $Utilities) {
   .$Item.FullName
}

#---[ Select an Environment ]---#
# Get the User's choice
$env_choice = selectEnv
# Process the choice
switch ($env_choice) {
   Prod {
      $csv_output_path = '\\etoprod\******\Exports\Report_Users_Prod.csv'
      $user_data = process_data 'Prod' 'api/xm/1/people?embed=roles&limit=1000'
    }
   Dev {
      $csv_output_path = '\\etoprod\******\Exports\Report_Users_Dev.csv'
      $user_data = process_data 'Dev' 'api/xm/1/people?embed=roles&limit=1000'
    }
   Test {
      Write-Output "Test is not an option. Choose wisely."
      exit 1
    }
   Default {
      Write-Output "Unknown Environment Choice."
      exit 1
   }
}

#---[ Process Users and Export ]---#
processUsersData
exportCsv $collated_user_data $csv_output_path
```

selectEnv.ps1

```
function selectEnv {
   $Title = "Environment:"
   $Info = "Please choose an environment"
   # Options
   $Prod = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Prod', 'Production environment'
   $Dev = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Dev', 'Development environment'
   $Test = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Test', 'Testing environment'
   $Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($Prod, $Dev, $Test)
   $Default = 0
   # Promp the User
   $Choice =  $host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title , $Info , $Options, $Default)
   $Result = $Options[$Choice].Label -Replace '&',''
   return $Result
}
```